# Modifying a JS file with data from plugin settings

Tags: plugins, javascript, options

I have a plugin that, among other things, has a javascript file that requires a few user specific settings. What would be the best way to get those settings into javascript from the plugin's settings parameters?

In other words, if I make those settings part of the settings page where the user can enter them, how would I best be able to get those values into javascript? Would I have to use something to append some script tags and set them via PHP on every page load? Would setting a cookie be a better way to do this?

Comment: This is a *really* great question and one that I've been planning to ask. Thanks for asking it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

better is, you use the functions of WP for this, a example for multilanguage:

```
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts' );
    function add_scripts($where) {
        wp_localize_script( 'post2media', 'post2media_strings', $this->localize_vars() );
    }
    function localize_vars() {

        $strings = array(
                'btntext'    => __( 'Link with post', INPSYDE_P2M_TEXTDOMAIN ),
                'txtallnone' => __( 'Include in gallery:', INPSYDE_P2M_TEXTDOMAIN ),
                'txtall'     => __( 'All', INPSYDE_P2M_TEXTDOMAIN ),
                'txtnone'    => __( 'None', INPSYDE_P2M_TEXTDOMAIN ),
                'ttlcb'      => __( 'Include image in this gallery', INPSYDE_P2M_TEXTDOMAIN )
            );

        return $strings;
    }
```

use this in js-file:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
buttonaddfunc = function() {
    btntext = post2media_strings.btntext;

    reg = /\d+/;
    $( '.savesend > .button' ) . each( function() {
        inputname = $( this ) . attr( 'name' );
        number = reg . exec( inputname );
        $( this ) . after( '<input type="submit" value="' + btntext + '" name="link[' + number + ']" class="button">' );
    } );
    $( '.describe-toggle-on' ).unbind( 'click', buttonaddfunc );
};
$( '.describe-toggle-on' ).bind( 'click', buttonaddfunc );
```

} );

Also see the [post from Otto](http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/)

Comment: I didn't really understand your code too well but I found the link very useful.

Comment: This is really excellent, thank you! I have been wondering how to do this for a really long time; thank you! I'd been wanting to ask it on the wp-hackers list but never did. Thank you again.

Comment: You can see on my last plugin post2media (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post2media/) for see an example on live plugin; the plugin has not so much source and i think this is great for read source and understand the solution.

Comment: Here's a simpler example that gets it down to the basics (you have a lot going on in your example): http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/best-practice-for-adding-javascript-code-to-wordpress-plugin

Comment: Since the link is dead, here's the original article : https://web.archive.org/web/20190422164736/http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/ and another very useful: https://web.archive.org/web/20190429195119/http://ottopress.com/2010/passing-parameters-from-php-to-javascripts-in-plugins

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways that you could do this, one of which I've done before, the other I haven't, but I have used for XML configuration files.

The first one is to include the variables in a script tag inside the WP header or footer, before the script tag where you include your JS file, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = "<?php echo "hello world"; /* the relevant PHP code to echo the data you require */ ?>";
    var slider_type = "<?php echo "nivo"; /* same again */ ?>";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/your_js_here"></script>
```

The other alternative would be to include the JS inside of a PHP file which is included inside of a script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/javascripts.php"></script>
```

Inside this file you would include your javascript, and as PHP would parse it you would be able to include PHP calls in a similar fashion to above, simply echoing out the data/options which you require. One thing to note is that you might need to set the headers for the output as `text/javascript`.

Personally I much prefer the first method, and is what I use when I have user changeable settings which affect javascript files.

Comment: Nice writeup. This is exactly what I've been doing. OTOH, @bueltge has the answer we've probably all been looking for; I know I have.