# Ajax, Permalinks and post_thumbnail

Tags: jquery, ajax

As i'm new to AJAX, i'm still learning a lot and have learned a lot over the past weeks. I do need some more assistance on an AJAX issue though:

I'm using the following code to display post_thumbnails in a slider which when clicked go to the specific portfolio piece:

```
<ul id='portfolio-list'>
     <?php query_posts('cat=16&post_type=portfolio'); ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <li class="<?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category ) { echo $category->slug . ' '; } ?>all">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                <a id="caseStudy" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/post-thumb.jpg" width="141" height="73" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" /></a>
                    <?php } ?>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; endif ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </ul>
```

What i'm looking to do is to have the portfolio piece content load on the same page.

I'm using this code:

```
var ajax_load = "<center><img style='margin-top: 150px;' src='<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/images/loader.gif' alt='Loading...' /></center>"; 

                var loadUrl = "http://localhost:8888/cnNew/?page_id=4"; 
                    $("#ourTeam").live('click', function(){
                        $("#teamLoad")
                            .html(ajax_load)
                            .load(loadUrl + " #innerTeam")
                    });
```

to load other items onto the page but can't seem to get this way of calling it to work with the dynamically listed content. Can someone provide some assistance on the best way to achieve what i'm looking to do or at least a direction?

Thanks!

Comment: are you making a cross domain request?

Comment: No, this is all in the same domain. Why was this question down ranked for no reason? It is a legitimate question.

Comment: Whoever voted this down please give @jetDL a reason. I see no reason it should have been voted down.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than me solve your problem may I suggest you consider using the more WordPress standard method of AJAX?

- [**WordPress Codex: AJAX**](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX)
- [**WordPress Codex: AJAX in Plugins**](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)
- [**How to manage ajax calls and JSON in WordPress**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3610/how-to-manage-ajax-calls-and-json-in-wordpress)
- [**How to Implement Ajax in WordPress Themes**](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wordpress/implement-ajax-wordpress-themes/)

If you have follow up questions let us know.

Comment: Thanks for the links! It appears WordPress needs to update their Developer Information articles on the first link since the majority of them are broken. You wouldn't happen to have any more resources that are theme specific rather than plugin specific would you? I think seeing all these articles on Ajax in plugins is creating a huge disconnect for me for some reason.

Comment: While i'm still interested in learning more on the proper way to use AJAX with WordPress, I have come up with the solution to my issue. If you do have anymore resources, please do post! Thank You.

Comment: @jetDL WordPress Codex is a wiki so anyone can update it.  As for plugin vs. theme, the code needed is essentially identical. In almost all cases, plugins and themes are just two different ways to package the same code.  Glad you found a solution though. But I've added another link at your request.