# How would implement StackExchange 'Questions with similar titles' for the FAQ on my wordpress site

Tags: plugins, search, cache, autocomplete

I want to have a FAQ page on my site which has a search box. As the user types in their question, a field below the search box is populated with FAQ answers with similar titles.

The exact same functionality as the StackExchange 'Questions with similar titles' feature:

> Questions with similar titles
>
> 4 Open Source Forum for wordpress
>   similar to stackexchange or
>   stackoverflow (1)
>
> 0 How to implement a WordPress
>   comments function? (2)

etc...

Answer (score 3):

The communication with the server happens via Ajax. I once wrote [a high-level overview of Ajax in WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3610/how-to-manage-ajax-calls-and-json-in-wordpress/3612#3612), but you can find many more examples [on this site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ajax) and around the web.

Next, you have to do a query that will find similar titles. I found some questions that might help you on Stack Overflow:

- [Suggestion For Finding Similar Rows In Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169933/suggestion-for-finding-similar-rows-in-mysql)
- [Display similar results from mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741713/display-similar-results-from-mysql)
- [Is Full Text search the answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614358/is-full-text-search-the-answer)