# Can't use get_results() in ajax query

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wpdb

I'm using a jquery ajax call to get certain data from wpdb and I'm getting the following message:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object in <b>C:\wamp\www\maps_en2\markers.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
```

This is the call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "markers.php",
    data: ({'southWestLat' : southWestLat , 'southWestLng' : southWestLng , 'northEastLat' : northEastLat , 'northEastLng' : northEastLng}),
    success: function(msg){
    alert( msg );
    }
});
```

And this is the called code - markers.php:

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT user_id, lat, lng FROM coordinates WHERE lat>".$_POST["southWestLat"]." and lat<".$_POST["northEastLat"]." and lng>".$_POST["southWestLng"]." and lng<".$_POST["northEastLng"];
    $rows = $wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT_K);
    ...
?>
```

What's strange is that when the php code was on the same file as the javascript (and instead of the parameters 'southWestLat' etc, I used numbers, then it worked.
I should state that the jquery is in a php file under twentyten theme folder but markers.php is under the root directory (couldn't use it when it was in the theme for some reason).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will not work because you call `example.com/markers.php` directly, and that file does not load anything from WordPress, like the `$wpdb` object.

You can include `wp-load.php`, but this might break if you move the WordPress installation to somewhere else. To be more in line with how Ajax calls in WordPress should be made, you should write it as a hook for `wp_ajax_[action]`. See [my introduction to Ajax in WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3610/how-to-manage-ajax-calls-and-json-in-wordpress/3612#3612) for more details.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer but it's way out of my league. I have to take the `wp-load.php` approach for now and I'll write a memo to deal with it when the installation is moved. I would appreciate it if you can further help despite of taking the less favored approach. I've edited my question and added the results with that include.

Comment: @Ash: No problem. What is this `header.php` file you are trying to load? Can you update the question with the complete file? Or come to [the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/stoppress), then we can discuss it in detail there.

Comment: I included `header.php` by mistake. Probably, looking at some example. I've now changed it to `wp-load.php` and everything's working! thanks a lot.